# How to create a custom array with map or another method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**I have this array that I bring from the backend:**

```js
[{
  timeDate: '2020-12-10T06:00:00.535+00:00',
  totTransApproved: 75,
  totTransDeclined: 3,
  totAmount: 5016
}, {
  timeDate: '2020-12-10T06:01:00.535+00:00',
  totTransApproved: 71,
  totTransDeclined: 4,
  totAmount: 11337
}, {
  timeDate: '2020-12-10T06:02:00.535+00:00',
  totTransApproved: 83,
  totTransDeclined: 6,
  totAmount: 14370
}]
```

**and i need to convert it to this form :**

```js
[{
  timeDate: '12/04/20 0:00',
  name: 'Approved',
  totTrans: 180,
  totAmount: 125,
}, {
  timeDate: '12/04/20 0:00',
  name: 'declined',
  totTrans: 10,
  totAmount: 12,
}]
```

**I have tried this way but I need both objects**

```js
const datums = records.map((item) => ({
  timeDate: item.timeDate,
  name: 'Aprobada',
  totTrans: item.totTransApproved,
  totAmount: item.totAmount,

}));
```

**How can I do it ?**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to split each object from the input into individual 'Approved' and 'Declined' objects. If this is correct you can return an array of two objects from the `map()`

```js
const records = [{timeDate: '2020-12-10T06:00:00.535+00:00',totTransApproved: 75,totTransDeclined: 3,totAmount: 5016}, {timeDate: '2020-12-10T06:01:00.535+00:00',totTransApproved: 71,totTransDeclined: 4,totAmount: 11337}, {timeDate: '2020-12-10T06:02:00.535+00:00',totTransApproved: 83,totTransDeclined: 6,totAmount: 14370}]

const datums = records.map((item) => (
  [
    { timeDate: item.timeDate,
      name: 'Approved',
      totTrans: item.totTransApproved,
      totAmount: item.totAmount
    },
    { timeDate: item.timeDate,
      name: 'Declined',
      totTrans: item.totTransDeclined,
      totAmount: item.totAmount
    }
  ]
  ));
  
  console.log(datums);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

or if you don't want them grouped by array use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flatten the returned array of objects.

```
const datums = records.flatMap((item) => (
  [
    { timeDate: item.timeDate,
      name: 'Approved',
      totTrans: item.totTransApproved,
      totAmount: item.totAmount
    },
    { timeDate: item.timeDate,
      name: 'Declined',
      totTrans: item.totTransDeclined,
      totAmount: item.totAmount
    }
  ]
  ));
```

Comment: You saved my life, thank you very much ..
I did it with flatMap